# “GitLab service restarted.” but is not :/

Tags: debian

I don't know what to do, I executed the script to start Gitlab, which says "GitLab service restarted.", but it's not : I can't access it via my browser nor the port is open when I call `netstat -tuplen | grep 8080` (I modified the port in `gitlab.yml` to 8080 because Apache is already running in 80).

I took a look at the log files (all of them) and nothing happens.

I forced the start manually by calling :

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sidekiq:stop
```

then

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sidekiq:start
```

Still no port is opened at 8080!

If I call a check (`bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`), here's the result :

```
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for gitlab user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.4.0 ? ... OK (1.4.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by gitlab:gitlab? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes
post-receive hooks in repos are links: ... can't check, you have no projects

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no

All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  Redownload the init script
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
Projects have satellites? ... can't check, you have no projects
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.7.10)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

For information :

- The error regarding the script up-to-date is because I did all the installation without `sudo`, and the script needs `sudo`, I replaced the line using `sudo` by : `su -c "bash -l -c \"$1\"" -s /bin/sh $APP_USER`
- I have changed the system user to `gitlab` (instead of `git`) because the `git` user was already present
- I correctly updated this information in `gitlab.yml`
- I also have the home set to `/home/gitlab` instead of `/home/git` but I updated the config files accordingly (`gitlab.yml` and `config.yml` from `gitlab-shell`)
- I also updated the changes in the init script
- I tried to run Gitlab with master and 5-2-stable.
- I'm using Debian Squeeze
- I installed the backports of Redis (for the >= 2.0.0 problem)

If I take a look at the sidekiq log, nothing seems abnormal :

```
2013-06-13T11:39:33Z 30287 TID-2nuf0 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 2.11.1 using redis://localhost:6379 with options {:namespace=>"resque:gitlab"}
2013-06-13T11:39:34Z 30287 TID-2nuf0 INFO: Running in ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
2013-06-13T11:39:34Z 30287 TID-2nuf0 INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2013-06-13T11:39:34Z 30287 TID-2nuf0 INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
```

I don't know what more to show, or do.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Does that still happens with 5-3-stable?

Comment: I don't know, I finally installed Redmine ... ;)